# axios aync wait is not waiting for response

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, promise

I am doing a axios.post and trying to update store with the result. To test await functionality, I am doing debug in server side and holding the flow by putting a break point. But in react side, it is not waiting for the response, getting executed the next lines early.

Someone please help to solve this problem.

```
export const createUser = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/save', data);
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_USER,
            payload: res.data
        });
        return Promise.resolve(res.data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    };
}
```

calling place

```
const handleSave = () => {
    let data = userState;
    console.log("data-->"+JSON.stringify(data));
    dispatch(createUser(data)).then(
      data => {
        console.log("respose->"+JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log("error->"+err);
    });
```

}

Comment: What is `dispatch` in `handleSave`?

Comment: What's the point of `let data = userState`? Working with two variables that have the same name is confusing.

Comment: "*it is not waiting for the response, getting executed the next lines early.*" - how so? Which lines are executed in which order?

Comment: Hi @trincot, const dispatch = useDispatch();

Comment: Hi @Bergi, userState is the local state variable which holds form values.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I am holding the flow in server side using break point. But in react side after await line it suddenly goes to catch block, the error is 'Request failed with status code 500, ERR_BAD_RESPONSE'.
It is not waiting for server side flow to be completed. So I worry in case of some slowness in server side, it will show 500 error right away.

Comment: That sounds like your server framework has implemented its own timeout or something. Look at the browser devtools network panel. What is the exact response sent by the server? I bet it *did* send a 500 status, your JS code is working fine.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, Thanks, I tried to override the axios timeout. But still it shows the same issue.
Now axios time out is 10000(ms) and server timeout is 5000.
used - axiosObj.defaults.timeout = 10000;

Comment: If you are having trouble with the server timeout, please post the exact request and response, as well as the server-side code. You can [edit] your question or [post a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). There is no problem with your react.js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. This was related to fall back controller implemented as part of cloud gateway. The mapping provided was PostMapping and as solution changed it to RequestMapping.
PostMapping will allow only post requests which will not accept preflight requests.